# Pick Folder in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am building an web app in flutter, where the user is required to pick a folder and I will read and upload all the files inside that folder to storage. Please help! I couldn't find any plugin to do so.

Comment: One thing you can do is, Instead of folder you can accept compressed files (`.zip`, `.rar`) and then you can uncompress that file and use the files inside in it. To do Unzipping you can use [flutter_archiver](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_archive). or else you can accept multiple files using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)

Answer (score -1):

"One thing you can do is, Instead of folder you can accept compressed files (.zip, .rar) and then you can uncompress that file and use the files inside in it. To do Unzipping you can use flutter_archiver. or else you can accept multiple files using file_picker – "

I completed about this but I think this(I will read and upload all the files inside that folder to storage) is impossible